# How do I rotate a warping grid without changing the warped image's orientation?

Tags: image-processing

I have a warping grid, that has to be applied to an image. When I apply the grid, I get the results I expect.

Now, I want to apply the same grid to the same image, but the image is modified in the following way: it is rotated 270 degrees counterclockwise.

The grid is stored in memory as an array of points. It is [-1, -1] - [1, 1] normalized. I am trying to rotate the whole thing around the origin, that is [0, 0] id est the center of the image. Also, I am trying to rotate in discrete steps of 90 degrees.

```
P1 P2 P3 

P4 P5 P6

P7 P8 P9
```

These are destination coordinates of the points in the image. For example, the lower right corner of the input image has coordinates of [1,1]. In the output image, this point is moved to [P9.x, P9.y] (a.k.a. forward mapping).

I transpose the matrix:

```
P1 P4 P7

P2 P5 P8

P3 P6 P9
```

Then I apply to every point the transformation

```
x = y'

y = -x',
```

where ' denotes old coordinate and lack of prime denotes new coordinate. I apply the derived grid to the rotate

However, I do not get the expected warp. This task seemed incredibly simple to me, but I find myself struggling with the strange behaviour for a third day. Could someone point out my mistake or a procedure to get things right?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Are you trying to rotate the grid about the origin?

Comment: @Phonon, thanks for the wellcoming, man!Yes, I am trying to rotate the grid around the origin i.e. it's center, in discrete 90-degree steps. I hope this question is on-topic in this SE forum.

Comment: I don't think you need to transpose. Your coordinate change should be sufficient.

Comment: Well, not transposing the grid causes the following: after warpig the image, it becomes rotated to zero rotation (was 270). I want the image to sustain it's orientation. Of course, I could be making a programming mistake somewhere.

Comment: I do the transposition so that the computer reads out the points in the correct order. The warper expects the first point to correspond to [-1, -1] and the last point to correspond to [1, 1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two dimensions, to rotate a point by a certain angle you need to multiply that point by a rotation matrix of the form:

$
\left[\begin{array}{c}x' \\y' \end{array}\right]
= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\y \end{array}\right]
$

Where $(x, y)$ is the old coordinate, $(x', y')$ is the new coordinate, and $\theta$ is the angle of (counterclockwise) rotation you want to apply.

Thus, for a rotation of 270 degrees, the matrix you apply is:

$
\left[\begin{array}{c}x' \\y' \end{array}\right]
= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos(270)& -\sin(270) \\\sin(270) & \cos(270)\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\y \end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{cc}0& 1 \\-1 & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\y \end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{c}y \\-x \end{array}\right]
$

There is a comprehensive [wikipedia page on rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions), explaining them in more detail, extending them to 3D, and sumarising some of their properties.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I derived the "x =; y = " part of the conversion in my answer. However this also rotates the warped image, and I don't want that.

Comment: Perhaps it's unclear what you were asking. I thought you had a set of coordinates describing your grid, and you wanted to transform those coordinates according to a rotation?

Comment: Basically, I needed to apply a grid to an image, but the image can be given rotated and the grid should be applied the same way, without changing the orientation of the image, just warping it. I commited a minor edit to the headline. If you feel you can edit my question to express it more clearly, please, by all means, do so!

Comment: Could you add a couple of images? For instance, the original image and the expected result? Also, do you know the angle the image has been rotated by?

Answer (score 1):

After three and a half days of cursing, a couple of beers with a friend helped solve the problem. My mistake was that the reordering of points needed to be not exactly transpose, but close. So:

**To rotate a grid 90 degrees counter-clockwise:**

- transpose the grid and reflect it along the horizontal central line
- apply the transformation

x = y'

y = -x',

where primes denote old coordinates.

**To rotate a grid 180 degrees**

- reflect the grid around its horizontal and around it's vertical axis
- apply the transformation

x = - x'

y = - y'

**To rotate a grid 270 degrees**:

- transpose the grid and reflect it along the vertical central line
- apply the transformation

x = - y'

y = x'